# Is there a way to include workbox service worker code within the main bundle in a webpacked application?

Tags: webpack, service-worker, workbox

I have a React SPA that I am trying to bundle as an importable library. The library exposes a function to mount the root component of the app into any page. The library is available via CDN.

I am using a service worker to cache requests to large media files within the app. I can use the service worker fine when viewing the page from my own domain. But when I try to use the library on a test website, I get an error:

```
DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The origin of the provided scriptURL ('https://<mydomain>') does not match the current origin ('http://localhost:3000').
```

Here is the basic layout of files:

```
CDN:
/spa
  /assets
    ...
  /index.html     << (SPA version)
  /bundle.js      << (SPA version, uses ../serviceworker.js)

/assets
  ...
/bundle.js        << Library version
/serviceworker.js << (Works for SPA, but not library)
```

(It's not the most efficient webpack currently)

Is there any way to keep service worker code bundled within the main package of my script so I do not need to register it from an external url?

I've tried looking through workbox documentation, but I have not been able to find any resources on this.